# Button changes size on hover and focus

Tags: css, javafx

I created new css file to apply to my button. Also in scene builder I've in Text options I've changed text size and color. Button changed its appearence correctly but now when I hover around it or change focus it changes it size (when button is focused it gets smaller, and when its out of focus it's get bigger unless you hover mouse above it). Why is that? Is it because some default button behaviour? If yes how can I disable that?

This is my css code, it's very simple:

```
.button1 {
    -fx-background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    -fx-border: none;
    -fx-padding: 15px 32px;
    -fx-text-align: center;
    -fx-text-decoration: none;
    -fx-display: inline-block;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There are no such properties in JavaFX as `-fx-display: inline-block` or `-fx-text-decoration` or `-fx-text-align` or `-fx-border`.  So, regardless of the hover and focus sizing issues that you have encountered, you likely have other issues.  See the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for a list of accepted documented properties.  To change the colour I would just recommend setting `-fx-base` in your style class, which you can find defined in [modena.css](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470).

Answer (score -1):

write this for hover and focus

```
.button1:hover,  .button1:focus{
        -fx-background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
        -fx-border: none;
        -fx-padding: 15px 32px;
        -fx-text-align: center;
        -fx-text-decoration: none;
        -fx-display: inline-block;
        -fx-font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: The question is tagged [javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) and many of the CSS attributes you use in this answer are not available within JavaFX CSS.